Angular x SCSS: Rgba does not evaluate HEX value
I'm trying to access the background colour of the Angular theme. It woks as a HEX value but I need to apply transparency to the colour.
I have this variable definition:
:root {
    --opacity: .15;
    --primary: #4caf50;
    --accent: #6a1b9a;
    --warn: #f44336;

exporting the function
@function getColor($color, $opacity: 1) {
    @return rgba(var(--#{$color}), $opacity);
}

with this function which is supposed to give the color with alpha value:
and somewhere in another component file there is:
@use "whatever" as UI;
[_nghost-ng-c2555015885] mat-sidenav[_ngcontent-ng-c2555015885] {
    outline: UI.getColor(primary, .25) 1px solid;
}

I would expect the colour to be evaluated but instead I just get plain text.

https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/wataBottl/stackblitz-starters-gxm7p4

That StackBlitz link is not working. Also rgba(#4caf50, 0.25) is not a valid color, at least not in my browser (Chrome). Are you looking for rgb(from #4caf50 r g b / 0.25)? See the docs

It works if you copy-paste it in the url bar. For some reason the ~ gets encoded and that's why it doesn't work.

You cannot use rgba() like that with a hex value, it needs to be converted to rgb first. Also rgba() is considered legacy syntax. Updated code with modern syntax:
@function getColor($color, $opacity: 1) {
    @return rgb(from var(--#{$color}) r g b / $opacity);
}

For more information, see the docs.
